# Write cron task from Tuesday 12 pm to Wednesday 12 pm for Celery

Tags: celery, cron-task, cronexpression, celery-task

I am trying to write a periodic `cron` task for `celery` which should execute every hour from Tuesday 12pm to Wednesday 12 pm. That is a 24 hour period but spans two different days. Is it possible to schedule this as a single task like 
`@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(<an expression equivalent to stated above>))`
At the moment I am writing two tasks: one with decorator:
`crontab(minute='0',hour='12-23',day_of_week='tue')` and another with
`crontab(minute='0',hour='0-11',day_of_week='wed')`
Some examples are given [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the two specifications you've created cannot be consolidated into the same rule.  The only real solution (less than ideal in most scenarios) that I can think of is to change the timezone under which Celery is executing using CELERY_TIMEZONE.  +/-12 hours from the timezone you currently have configured with Celery would do the trick, though there very obviously could be other ramifications to doing this.

Comment: Yea, thats a workaround, but I dont think it should be ever done. It would probably screw the whole tasks scheduled. Will stick with splitting the tasks into two days. Thanks

Comment: Yeap.  In total agreement.  I think it might make sense from a feature standpoint for Celery to support unioning multiple rules together.